# Creating an Array of Strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, command-line-arguments, c-strings

I am having this issue, where I use a command-line interface. 
I am trying to store the input in an array of strings. But When I run my code
I get a segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int num, char **str) {

    int i;

    char owner[20];
    char *keys[5];

    int j = 0;


    for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {

        if (i == 1) {

            strcpy(owner, str[i]);
            printf("%s", owner);
        }
        else {

            keys[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(keys[j], str[i]);

            printf("%s", keys[j]);

            j++;

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: `keys[i] =` and  `strcpy(keys[j]`

Comment: Typo: `keys[i]` should be `keys[j]`.

Comment: FYI, the arguments to `main()` are conventionally named `argc` and `argv`. Making up your own names will just confuse other programmers.

Comment: It would make more sense to copy `str[1]` to `owner` unconditionally outside the loop, and start the loop at `i = 2`.  The whole if/else block in the loop is then unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the else statement you should write

```
    else {

        keys[j] = malloc( strlen( str[i] ) + 1 );
        strcpy(keys[j], str[i]);

        printf("%s", keys[j]);

        j++;
    }
```

Also you should provide that the array owner is large enough to store the string str[1].

Comment: This should just be closed as a typo, it's not worth a real answer.

Comment: @Barmar Apart from the typo I suggested to use strlen.:)